# How can I check if a string contains only spaces and alphabet letters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I check if a string contains only spaces and alphabet letters?

I'm not sure about how to implement it into my code. At the moment I have

```
phrase.match(/[[:alpha:]]+[[:blank:]]/)
```

which I thought would return true if the phrase contains only alphabet letters and spaces but this isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see sample input data, and your expected outputs. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 6):

Just combine the both char classes. And the anchors are much needed here.

```
phrase.match(/^[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+$/)
```

This would find a match only if the input string contain letters or spaces.

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/gEOa2fDfG2)

Comment: jealousy I guess, as always

Answer (score 1):

Avinash Raj provided almost correct answer, so I'll just build up on that.

Just combine the both char classes. And the anchors are much needed here.

```
phrase.match(/\A[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+\z/)
```

Example:

```
"ds ds sd ds".match(/\A[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+\z/)
=> #<MatchData "ds ds sd ds">

"dad56".match(/\A[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+\z/)
=> nil

"sdfd Ajds".match(/\A[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+\z/)
=> #<MatchData "sdfd Ajds">

"sdfd Ajds".match(/\A[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+\z/)
=> #<MatchData "sdfd Ajds">

"hghds /*".match(/\A[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+\z/)
=> nil

"abcd def SURPRISE".match(/\A[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+\z/)
=> #<MatchData "abcd def SURPRISE">

"abcd def\nSURPRISE".match(/\A[[:alpha:][:blank:]]+\z/)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative match.

```
phrase !~ /[^[:alpha:][:blank:]]/
```

Comment: I think this would return true for an empty string.